# How to allow user to input array index along with the values of the array?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main(){

string m;
int n;

cout << "How many elements would you like to sort?" << endl;

cin >> n;  //index for the array



cout << "Enter " << n << " numbers seperated by a comma to be sorted" <<   endl;

cin >> m;

string unsortedNumbers[n]={m};  // values inputed stored as array values
cout << m << endl;

std::sort(m.begin() , m.end());  //sorting string m
std::cout<< m << endl;

}
```

I understand that the code is wrong, if you run the code the 'string' works properly until sorting. When sorting numbers above 10 it breaks them down as 1 and 0. Also all the commas get sorted and say your input was 2,3,4,5 your output will look something like ,,,,2345. So my question is how can I let the user select the index size while then allowing whatever number they input to determine the number of variables to then be sorted?

Comment: There are things called `#PRAGMA` which can turn this dynamic interface on and off. If you would like to know more, you can google it. I talked with an associate of Bjarne Stroustrup about it. There's some numberthat goes wth it.

Comment: Also, you need a vector array of strings. Or an array of ints. You have to know what you want. You can test it with function overloading. Like

Answer (score 2):

I can only do this in a quiet fussy way since I turn string to char* and finally turn char* to string again. In my view,The string classes of the C++ standard library enable you to use strings as normal types that cause no problems for the user. Thus, you can copy, assign, and compare strings as fundamental types without worrying or bothering about whether there is enough memory or for how long the internal memory is valid. However,that also means we can only use interfaces and can't do whatever we want to do.You know,string based on the basic template class basic_string<> and looks like container more than char*.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string m;
    int n;
    cout << "How many elements would you like to sort?" << endl;
    cin >> n;  //index for the array
    cout << "Enter " << n << " numbers seperated by a comma to be sorted" <<   endl;
    cin >> m;


    //string c[n]={m};
    vector<int> unsortedNumbers;
    const char* p=m.c_str();
    int i=0;
    while(i<n){//or *p!='\0'
        i++;
        unsortedNumbers.push_back(atoi(p));
        while(*p>='0'&&*p<='9') p++;
        if(i<n)p++;
    }
    //std::sort(m.begin() , m.end());  //sorting string m
    sort(unsortedNumbers.begin(), unsortedNumbers.end());
    for_each(unsortedNumbers.begin(), unsortedNumbers.end(), [](int x){cout<<x<<" ";});
    //now we have a sorted array and its type is double[]
    char arr[n][m.length()];
    for(int i=0;i!=n;i++) {
        if(i!=n-1) sprintf(arr[i],"%d,",unsortedNumbers[i]);
        else sprintf(arr[i],"%d",unsortedNumbers[i]);
    }
    m.clear();
    for(auto i:arr)  m+=i;
    cout<<m;
}
```

Comment: I can almost get behind this answer. Problems: `int unsortedNumbers[n];`  is invalid in C++. Variable Length Arrays are supported by extension in some but not all compilers. `i` is unbounded and can overshoot the end of the array. Ignores that the input is comma separated.

Comment: Suggestions: rather than atoi, which forces you to go hunting the end of the number, use strtol because it tells you where the end of the number was.

Comment: Just realized something. that last `p++` int he parsing loop is supposed to eliminate the comma. It fooled me because in "1,2,3,4,5" it consumes the terminating null, and you can probably guess what that does.

Comment: Thanks,I actually miss something. Variable Length Arrays are supported by extension in some but not all compilers so using vector<int> is much better.It's unsafe to do like I do. str_c() turn a string into char* and at the end there is a '\0' so the last `p++` reach the '\0',maybe?

Comment: 1,2,3,4,5,\0 works, 1,2,3,4,5\0 does not because of that last p++, but you should get away with it with the `i<n` in the new version. Have to run it to find out.

Answer (score 1):

the simplest way to let the user enter the size of array and then sort and print the result on screen is by using STD approach like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "How many elements would you like to sort?" << std::endl;
    std::size_t n;
    std::cin >> n;  //index for the array

    std::cout << "Enter " << n << " numbers seperated by a comma to be sorted" << std::endl;

    std::vector<char> vec;
    vec.reserve(n + n - 1); // array size + commas

    // get array values from user
    std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<char>(std::cin), vec.capacity(), std::back_inserter(vec));

    // remove commas
    vec.erase(std::remove(vec.begin(), vec.end(), ','), vec.end());

    // sort array
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());

    // print it 
    std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout, " "));
    // input: 2, 3, 1
    // output: 1 2 3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FunctionOne(int &arr[]) {}

void main() {
    int n;
    cout << "How many elements would you like to sort?" << endl;

    cin >> n;  //index for the array



    cout << "Enter " << n << " numbers. Separate by <enter> to be sorted" << endl;
#PRAGMA NUMBER
    int arr[n];
    for (int m:arr)
        cin >> m;
    FunctionOne(&arr);
}
```

So you don't have what we call spaghetti code, you can put sort in a function. It's good practice.

Comment: It's just an overload. I'll fix itup

Comment: I thought he was trying to do a overload on `sort()`. The string messed me up. @user4581301

Comment: To be perfectly fair, y0ur code is great. Mines just mine. You just need to make sure that y0ur input is a int array, not a string,

Comment: Whatever it is, it isn't C++.  A C++ compiler would generate a diagnostic for the line `int arr[n];` because `n` is not a legal array bound (it isn't a compile-time constant integral expression)

Comment: Refer to my comments under the question.

Comment: No longer random garbage, but still doesn't answer OP's question.

Comment: How should `FunctionOne` know the size of the array?

Comment: It doesn't need to, not in my experience.. I'm passing by reference though,so wont a sizeof() work?

Comment: Okay, now i see what youre asking. You need to use the #PRAGMA call.

Comment: This is the question @neilkirk

Comment: `FunctionOne` will not be able to tell the size of the array (number of elements). You will need to pass it as a second parameter.

Comment: Oh okay. If I pass by value, is it still the same? Pointers?

Comment: `FunctionOne(int * arr[])` is actually passing an array of int pointers. You need `FunctionOne(int arr[], size_t size)`

Comment: `sizeof` is resolved at compile time, whereas the size of the array passed to the function could vary at run-time. Therefore `sizeof` an array parameter (unless passed by reference) only gives the size of a pointer to an element.

Comment: The funny part is I meant to do byref. :-)